# I can't properly print values from an input by using document.getElementById();

Tags: javascript, dom, input, getelementbyid

I can't properly print values from an input by using document.getElementById();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewpoint" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Cálculadora C.O.C</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h2 class="logo">C.O.C</h2>
            <nav class="navigation">
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <a href="#"></a>
                <button class="btnLogin-popup">Calculadora</button>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="form-box login">
                    <h2>C.O.C</h2>
                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="leaf-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                            <input id="area" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <span class="icon"><ion-icon name="earth-outline"></ion-icon></span>
                            <input id="bioma" type="Bioma" required>
                        </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="teste()">Calcular</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
<script>
        
    var xum = document.getElementById("area").value
    var bioma = document.getElementById("bioma").value

    function teste(){
                    console.log(xum)
                    console.log(bioma)
                }
```

Basically I'm trying to use the function "teste()" to print out values from "area" and "bioma" onclick of a button.

Nothing appears in the console.

Comment: It should log something, but your page is refreshing right (since you're submitting a form)? So it disappears soon after?

Comment: You're reading values once on init phase. Unless I understood your pattern wrong, the default value is empty. Hence, you should read the values every time in `teste`

Comment: If you need to use those values after pressing the button then you shouldn't use a form and a submit button that will redirect you to another page and lose your data

Comment: `var xum = document.getElementById("area").value
    var bioma = document.getElementById("bioma").value` is going to read the values when the page loads. The value changing in the input does not keep updating those variables.

Answer (score 1):

> Nothing appears in the console.

What do you *expect* to appear in the console and why?  You're capturing these values immediately upon page load:

```
var xum = document.getElementById("area").value
var bioma = document.getElementById("bioma").value
```

And when the page loads, what are those values?:

```
<input id="area" required>
<!-- ... -->
<input id="bioma" type="Bioma" required>
```

There are no values.  So there's nothing to print to the console.  If you want the user to be able to enter values and *then* read those values, don't read the values until *after* the user has entered them:

```
function teste() {
  var xum = document.getElementById("area").value
  var bioma = document.getElementById("bioma").value
  console.log(xum)
  console.log(bioma)
}
```

---

**Additionally**, it looks like you're probably submitting the form which will reload the page.  If you don't want that to happen then change the button type from `submit` to just `button`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="teste()">Calcular</button>
```

And/or remove the `<form>` element entirely since you're not using it for anything.